# How to make boxes scroll horizontally?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native, and I'm trying to make a social media app. I want to make it where you can scroll vertically to view certain posts, and then scroll horizontally to see other posts by the same user. I downloaded a UI framework, and it scrolls vertically, but how would I make the posts scroll horizontally?

Home.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {View,Text,Image,ImageBackground,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {ScrollView,TextInput} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Icon from '@expo/vector-icons/Entypo';
import Posts from '../screens/Posts'


export default class Home extends React.Component{
    state={
        popularSelected:true
    }
    onTabPressed=()=>{
        this.setState({popularSelected:!this.state.popularSelected})
    }
    render(){
        return(
          <ScrollView
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            style={{
                height:"100%",
                backgroundColor:"#b5f8d9"
            }}
          >
              <View style={{ 
                  
                  height:260,
                  width:"100%",
                  paddingHorizontal:35
              }}>
                  <View style={{ 
                      flexDirection:"row",
                      width:"100%",
                      paddingTop:40,
                      alignItems:"center"
                  }}>
                      <View style={{
                          width:"50%"
                      }}>
                          <Image source={require('../images/Untitled.png')}
                            style={{width:20,height:20}}/>
                      </View>
                      <View style={{
                          width:"50%",
                          alignItems:"flex-end",
                      }}>
                          <Icon name = "dots-two-vertical"
                            size={22}
                            color="#d2d2d2"
                            style={{
                                marginRight:-7,
                                marginTop:7
                            }}/>
                      </View>
                  </View>


<View>
    <Image source={require('../images/logoVizzey.jpg')} style={{width:200, height:80}}/>
</View>
                {/* <Text style={{
                    fontFamily:"Bold",
                    fontSize:25,
                    color:"#FFF",
                    paddingVertical:25
                }}>Vizzey</Text> */}

                <View style={{
                    flexDirection:"row",
                    borderColor:"#9ca1a2",
                    borderRadius:20,
                    borderWidth:0.2,
                    paddingVertical:5,
                    alignItems:"center"
                }}>
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="search inispiration ..."
                        style={{
                            paddingHorizontal:20,
                            fontFamily:"Medium",
                            fontSize:11,
                            width:"90%",
                            color:"#9ca1a2"
                        }}
                    />
                    <Icon name="magnifying-glass"
                          size={15}
                          color="#9ca1a2"/>
                </View>

              </View>

              <View style={{
                  backgroundColor:"#FFF",
                  borderTopLeftRadius:40,
                  borderTopRightRadius:40,
                  height:1000,
                  paddingHorizontal:35
              }}>
                  <View style={{
                      flexDirection:"row",
                      paddingTop:20
                  }}>
                      <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={this.onTabPressed}
                        style={{
                            borderBottomColor:this.state.popularSelected ? "#044244":"#FFF",
                            borderBottomWidth:4,
                            paddingVertical:6
                        }}
                      >
                          <Text style={{
                              fontFamily:"Bold",
                              color:this.state.popularSelected ? "#044244":"#9ca1a2"
                          }}>MOST POPULAR</Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>


                      <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={this.onTabPressed}
                        style={{
                            borderBottomColor:this.state.popularSelected ? "#FFF":"#044244",
                            borderBottomWidth:4,
                            paddingVertical:6,
                            marginLeft:30
                        }}
                      >
                          <Text style={{
                              fontFamily:"Bold",
                              color:this.state.popularSelected ? "#9ca1a2":"#044244"
                          }}>RECENT</Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>

                  <View style={{
                      flexDirection:"row"
                  }}>
                      <Posts
                        onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail')}
                        name="Max Bator"
                        profile={require('../images/p1.jpg')}
                        photo={require('../images/5.jpg')}
                      />

                      <View style={{
                          height:160,
                          backgroundColor:"#3c636c",
                          width:20,
                          marginLeft:20,
                          marginTop:120,
                          borderTopLeftRadius:20,
                          borderBottomLeftRadius:20
                      }}>

                      </View>

                  </View>



                  <View style={{
                      flexDirection:"row"
                  }}>
                     
                      <View style={{
                          height:160,
                          backgroundColor:"#3c636c",
                          width:20,
                          marginLeft:-40,
                          marginRight:20,
                          marginTop:120,
                          borderTopRightRadius:20,
                          borderBottomRightRadius:20
                      }}>

                      </View>

                      <Posts
                        onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail')}
                        name="Erka Berka"
                        profile={require('../images/p2.jpg')}
                        photo={require('../images/6.jpg')}
                      />

                  </View>

                  <View style={{
                      flexDirection:"row"
                  }}> 
                      <Posts
                        onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail')}
                        name="Max Bator"
                        profile={require('../images/p1.jpg')}
                        photo={require('../images/3.jpg')}
                      />

                      <View style={{
                          height:160,
                          backgroundColor:"#3c636c",
                          width:20,
                          marginLeft:20,
                          marginTop:120,
                          borderTopLeftRadius:20,
                          borderBottomLeftRadius:20
                      }}>

                      </View>

                  </View>
              </View>

          </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}
```

Posts.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {View,Text,Image,ImagBackground, ImageBackground} from 'react-native';
import Icon from "@expo/vector-icons/Entypo"
import {TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';


export default class Posts extends React.Component{
    state={
        liked:false
    }
    onLike=()=>{
        this.setState({liked:!this.state.liked})
    }
    render(){

        const {name,profile,photo,onPress} = this.props

        return(
            <View>
               <View style={{
                   flexDirection:"row",
                   paddingTop:25,
                   alignItems:"center"         
                }}>
                    <View style={{width:"20%"}}>
                            <Image
                                source={profile}
                                style={{
                                    width:45,
                                    height:45,
                                    borderRadius:13
                                }}
                                />
                    </View>
                    <View style={{
                        width:"60%"
                    }}>
                        <Text style={{
                            fontFamily:"Bold",
                            fontSize:14,
                            color:"#044244"
                        }}>{name}</Text>

                        <Text style={{
                            fontFamily:"Medium",
                            fontSize:12,
                            color:"#9ca1a2"
                        }}>
                            2 mins ago
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{
                        width:"20%",
                        alignItems:"flex-end"
                    }}>
                        <Icon
                            name="sound-mix"
                            color="#044244"
                            size={20}
                        />
                    </View>
               </View>

               <View style={{
                   flexDirection:"row",
                   width:"100%",
                   paddingTop:20
               }}>
                    <ImageBackground 
                    source={photo}
                    style={{
                        width:"100%",
                        height:220,
                    }}
                    imageStyle={{
                        borderRadius:30
                    }}
                    >
                        <View style={{
                            height:"100%",
                            flexDirection:"row",
                            alignItems:'flex-end',
                            justifyContent:"flex-end"
                        }}>


                            <TouchableOpacity
                                onPress={onPress}
                                style={{
                                    marginBottom:20,
                                    borderRadius:5,
                                    padding:5,
                                    backgroundColor:"#e8e8e8"
                                }}
                            >
                                <Icon name="forward"
                                color="#044244"
                                size={20}/>
                            </TouchableOpacity>


                            <TouchableOpacity
                                onPress={this.onLike}
                                style={{
                                    marginBottom:20,
                                    borderRadius:5,
                                    padding:5,
                                    backgroundColor:"#e8e8e8",
                                    marginLeft:10,
                                    marginRight:20
                                }}
                            >
                                <Icon name= {this.state.liked === true ? "heart":"heart-outlined"} 
                                color= {this.state.liked===true? "red":"#044244"}
                                size={20}/>
                            </TouchableOpacity>

                        </View>
                    </ImageBackground>
               </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Here is a picture of the UI:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using a flatlist? https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#horizontal

Answer (score 0):

Add horizontal attribute to ScrollView or any Scroll component.

```
<ScrollView horizontal></ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have added ImageBackground twice in your imports in post.js file

to make it scroll horizontally, use the property horizontal

```
<ScrollView 
  horizontal
 >
  //other code goes here
 </ScrollView>
```

see docs
https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview